# CDocument call UpdateAllViews() before CView::OnInitialUpdate(), is this good?

Tags: c++, mfc

I've got a MFC existing project. The CDocument class can update views even when view is not initially updated. Views are of CFormView type, and I know there will be DoDataExchange() called in CFormView::OnInitialUpdate().

Will this cause problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it depends on how you implemented `OnUpdate` in the view classes of your document. `UpdateAllViews` is nothing more than an iteration over all views of your document which calls `OnUpdate` for every view. The base implementation of `OnUpdate` only invalidates the view rectangle. If you access FormView controls in your `OnUpdate` methods the result might depend on whether `OnInitialUpdate` has been called before or not. Otherwise it probably doesn't matter if you call `UpdateAllViews` before or after `OnInitialUpdate`.